# Browser automation: Add script to run in my current Chrome tab

Tags: google-chrome, browser-automation

I want to write a small script that works in my current Chrome tab and can access elements on the page, click buttons, scroll, dismiss modals etc.

Why? I have an internal app that is really tedious to use and I want to automate a particular workflow.

What does not work:

1. **Selenium** etc: Selenium opens an anonymous browser window. This internal web app has complex authentication involving 2fa - so its better if my code lives in my personal browser window.
2. **Chrome extension**: I don't want to publish my extension publicly but just distribute it inside the company. Also, not sure if Chrome extensions allow you to scroll and click in the page.
3. **Greasemonkey**: This is for Firefox but we only use Chrome

What are my options?

Answer (score -1):

pathikrit, chrome.tabs.executeScript method will be your script's entry point into the current tab's environment, allowing you to manipulate the page as needed.

```
javascript

chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: `
  // Let's get those buttons clicking!
  document.querySelector('your-button-selector').click();
  console.log('Click! That was easy.');
`});
```

In the snippet, replace 'your-button-selector' with the actual selector of the button you want to automate clicking. You can insert any JavaScript you need in place of the console.log call to manipulate the page.

About the rest of your question - maybe someone has a better background to help you.